# PHP: paging with Ajax not working correctly

Tags: php, ajax

I'm fetching records from a database and displaying them in gruops using php and ajax.

The script below (found somewhere) is almost working, but it seems that when you are on the first page and clicking "Next" you are taken to the LAST page.

Only when clicking the numbers individually, the paging is correct.

I can provide a test link in a PM if needed.

index.php:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results" ).load( "pages.php"); //load initial records
    //executes code below when user click on pagination links
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
        $("#results").load("pages.php",{"page":page}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
        });
    });
});
</script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

pages.php:

```
<?php
// continue only if $_POST is set and it is a Ajax request
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    include (realpath(__DIR__ . '/../db.php'));
    // Get page number from Ajax POST
    if (isset($_POST["page"])) {
        $page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter number
        if (!is_numeric($page_number)) {
            die('Invalid page number!');
        }
    }
    else {
        $page_number = 1; //if there's no page number, set it to 1
    }
    // get total number of records from database for pagination
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $DBtable . " ORDER BY dates DESC";
    $rs = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($rs === false) {
        trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    else {
        $get_total_rows = $rs->fetch_row(); //hold total records in variable
    }
    // break records into pages
    $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0] / $item_per_page);
    // get starting position to fetch the records
    $page_position = (($page_number - 1) * $item_per_page);
    // Limit our results within a specified range.
    $rs = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, title, description, dates, clicks FROM " . $DBtable . " ORDER BY dates DESC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");
    $rs->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
    $rs->bind_result($id, $title, $description, $dates, $clicks); //bind variables to prepared statement

    echo '<ul class="contents">';
    while($rs->fetch()){ //fetch values
        echo '<li>';
        echo  $id. '. <strong>' .$name.'</strong> &mdash; '.$description;
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '<div align="center">';
    /* We call the pagination function here to generate Pagination link for us. */
    echo paginate_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows[0], $total_pages);
    echo '</div>';
    exit;
}
// ############### pagination function #########################################
function paginate_function($item_per_page, $current_page, $total_records, $total_pages) {
    $pagination = '';
    if ($total_pages > 0 && $total_pages != 1 && $current_page <= $total_pages) { //verify total pages and current page number
        $pagination.= '<ul class="pagination">';
        $right_links = $current_page + 3;
        $previous = $current_page - 3; //previous link
        $next = $current_page + 1; //next link
        $first_link = true; //boolean var to decide our first link

        if ($current_page > 1) {
            $previous_link = ($previous == 0) ? 1 : $previous;
            $pagination.= '<li class="class="page-item" first"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="1" title="First">&laquo;</a></li>'; //first link
            $pagination.= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $previous_link . '" title="Prev">&lt;</a></li>'; //previous link
            for ($i = ($current_page - 2); $i < $current_page; $i++) { //Create left-hand side links
                if ($i > 0) {
                    $pagination.= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $i . '" title="Page' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
                }
            }
            //set first link to false
            $first_link = false;
        }
        if ($first_link) { //if current active page is first link
            $pagination.= '<li class="page-item active first"><a class="page-link" href="#">' . $current_page . '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
        }
        elseif ($current_page == $total_pages) { //if it's the last active link
            $pagination.= '<li class="page-item active last"><a class="page-link" href="#">' . $current_page . '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
        }
        else { //regular current link
            $pagination.= '<li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">' . $current_page . '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
        }
        for ($i = $current_page + 1; $i < $right_links; $i++) { //create right-hand side links
            if ($i <= $total_pages) {
                $pagination.= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $i . '" title="Page ' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
            }
        }
        if ($current_page < $total_pages) {
            $next_link = ($i > $total_pages) ? $total_pages : $i;
            $pagination.= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $next_link . '" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>'; //next link
            $pagination.= '<li class="page-item last"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $total_pages . '" title="Last">&raquo;</a></li>'; //last link
        }
        $pagination.= '</ul>';
    }
    //return pagination links
    return $pagination;
}
// Free memory
$rs->free();
// Close connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

This is the current parsed html of the pager:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item active first"><a class="page-link" href="#">1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="2" title="Page 2">2</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="3" title="Page 3">3</a></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="4" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>
  <li class="page-item last"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="4" title="Last">»</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post your pagination html so i get idea what u pass on next and previous button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try like below in your `paginate_function()`

$next_link = ($i > $total_pages) ? $total_pages : $i;

to

$next_link = (($current_page + 1) > $total_pages) ? $total_pages : $current_page + 1;

Comment: That works. Thanks! But it seems I have the same issue with the Previous link. What should I change that one to?

Comment: $previous = $current_page - 3; //previous link replace with $previous = $current_page - 1;

Comment: also approve answer if you got your solutions so other user will get solutions quickly

Answer (score 0):

Please make changes in paginate_function function as below

```
if ($current_page < $total_pages) {
        $next_link = ($i > $total_pages) ? $total_pages : $i;
        $pagination.= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $next_link . '" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>'; //next link
        $pagination.= '<li class="page-item last"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $total_pages . '" title="Last">&raquo;</a></li>'; //last link
}
```

Change this to

```
if ($current_page < $total_pages) {
        $next_link = ($i > $total_pages) ? $total_pages : $next;
        $pagination.= '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $next_link . '" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>'; //next link
        $pagination.= '<li class="page-item last"><a class="page-link" href="#" data-page="' . $total_pages . '" title="Last">&raquo;</a></li>'; //last link
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to the OP and to other that may read this question to explain what you have changed and why

Comment: @Danish Husain > Thanks. Could you be a little more clear?